# Texture appears to "flake" off the model at certain camera angles. Image renders those areas as transparent

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, transparency

[image]Example of issue

As you can see above I get this white streak and thing that looks like its just a reflection with a lamp that's too bright.
It changes as I adjust the camera but no matter what happens if I render that whole area is transparent. I can adjust the camera and remove the lamps and the issue persists

I went through to make sure that I did not have any overlapping geometry which I confirmed.
I tried rebuilding the chessboard model. As soon as I started the second step and began extruding from the plane I placed it happened even before applying a material or texture.

Has anybody encountered this before, or have an idea on what might be causing this?

I had an idea while typing this that I might rebuild it again but this time use a cube and scale it as I need instead of extruding from a plane as I had weird issues before this while doing that as well. I would still appreciate thoughts or idea.

---

[image]

Image with materials tab open.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your material's node tree and settings?

Comment: I posted a screenshot with my materials tab open. I never messed with any settings below roughness.

Comment: I just got confirmation that this issue is due to my hardware being AMD.

Comment: you might want to delete your question then.